# cx_freeze sre_constants.error nothing to repeat

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I updated Python from 3.3.2 to 3.3.3, but that might not be the problem.
If I start my python application directly it is OK.

But when I freeze it to exe with cx_freeze the sqlalchemy connection in `C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py` line 184 uses `re.compile` and throws

`C:\Python\32-bit\3.3\lib\sre_compile.py` line 362 in `_simple`

`sre_constraints.error: nothing to repeat`

but in my `sre_compile.py` file on line 362 is no raise error nothing to repeat. cx_freeze must use an old version of the file.

When I write this code:

```
import sre_compile
print(sre_compile)
```

and create an exe it prints out: `<module 'sre_compile' (frozen)>` and also it has no attribute `__file__`
I tried to remove all `__pycache__` dirs from my system and nothing happend.

How to tell cx_freeze to take the new version of the sre_compile module?

Comment: Make sure you have completely removed the build directory where your application is frozen, and try freezing anew. If that doesn't work, look at the output when you freeze your app to see where it's finding the various `sre_` modules.

Comment: In the freeze process output are `re`, `sre_*` modules but have no file assigned to it. Like the cx_freeze had its own versions. But I uninstalled the cx_freeze and installed an older version (4.3.2 -> 4.3.1) and now it is working. I dont know where was the problem, but it is (for now) solved.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I don't know if it was the older version or just reinstalling that made it work.

Comment: Yes, I just had this issue on our build server. I installed the latest version of cx_freeze and it fixed this problem.