# Importing matplotlib.pyplot and BeautifulSoup with cxFreeze

Tags: python, matplotlib, beautifulsoup, cx-freeze

I am attempting to compile an executable for my python script using cxFreeze. Out of the many libraries which I need to import for my script, two seem to fail with cxFreeze. In particular, consider the following test.py script:

```
print('matplotlib.pyplot')
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

compiling this with cxFreeze and running gives the following output:

[image: matplotlib cxFreeze problem]

separately, the following test.py script:

```
print('BeautifulSoup from bs4')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

after being compiled with cxFreeze, produces the following output:
[image: BeautifulSoup cxFreeze problem]

My setup.py file for cxFreeze looks as follows:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "myname",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "some description",
    executables = [Executable("test.py", base = None)]    
)
```

I am running Python 3.3 x86, and am using a 32 bit version of cxFreeze (most recent) on Windows 7.

I am having trouble chasing down this issue. For one, the directory "C:\Python\32-bit..." doesn't exist on my computer, so I am unclear as to why cxFreeze is trying to look there. Does anyone have any idea how to approach this, or perhaps has already dealt with this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some digging around, I was able to resolve the issue. For those who may be encountering the same issue, this is what solved it for me:

For the issue with matplotlib: I simply needed to explicitly specify to cxFreeze to include matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg. My setup file ended up looking like this:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
packages = ['matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg']

setup(
    name = "myname",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "some description",
    options = {'build_exe': {'packages':packages}},
    executables = [Executable("test.py", base = None)]    
)
```

As for the BeautifulSoup issue: There are a couple of posts around the web that have dealt with this issue: [cx_freeze sre_constants.error nothing to repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515742/cx-freeze-sre-constants-error-nothing-to-repeat), https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/59/sre_constantserror-nothing-to-repeat. 
The relevant conclusion: something is wrong with the 4.3.2 build of cxFreeze that causes this issue. I simply used cxFreeze 4.3.1 to build my app and the problem was solved. It may also be possible to rebuild 4.3.2 locally and have the issue be resolved, but I did not attempt this solution.

Comment: +1 You're also going to need to explicitly include matplotlib's data files if you want to use the default toolbars, etc.  Basically, you want to have the key/value `"include_files":[(matplotlib.get_data_path(), "mpl-data")` in addition to `'packages'` in `build_exe`.  Not to plug my own answer too much, but if it helps, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021297/share-image-from-mpldatacursor-with-others/22024663#22024663